# How would one go about solving the following partial derivative?

Tags: partial-derivative

Let:
$$f(x,t)=\frac{8x^2-101+6t^2}{x^2-6x+1+3t}$$

What method would I use to find $\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}f(x,t)$?

Comment: The Quotient rule?

Comment: It's literally a normal derivative. Pretend the $t$ is just a constant, like the number $5$.

Answer (score 2):

### Hint

Use the quotient rule:

$$\frac d{dx}\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)=\frac{f'(x)g(x)-f(x)g'(x)}{g(x)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

[image: simply this equation further.]

In partial derivative, while differentiating with respect to x, terms having only 't' are treated as constants.

Comment: fyi, pictures of text are generally discouraged here. Try to type out the answer in TeX if you can

Comment: I don't know how to use it. And would you mind telling me why pictures of text are discouraged here?

Comment: They're impossible to search for. [Here's a quick tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)